Scripting the process of granting privilege identity management in Azure
I am trying to script out the process of setting up Azure PIM. I have got the script below but it doesnt work correctly. As the B2C doesnt work when tested.
Not sure where its going wrong here, but I believe its possible to automate the process and that of assigning and configuring PIM on Azure entra roles also.
# Login to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

# Variables
$subscriptionId = "xxx"
$resourceGroupName = "my-rg"
$azureAdGroupName = "RG_OWNER_GROUP"

# Set the subscription context
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

# Get the Resource Group
$resourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName

if (-not $resourceGroup) {
    Write-Host "Resource group '$resourceGroupName' not found."
    exit
}

# Enable PIM for the role assignment
# Note: This step requires the AzureAD module and the correct permissions to enable PIM.
# Install the AzureAD module if not already installed
if (-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name AzureAD)) {
    Install-Module -Name AzureAD -Force -AllowClobber
}

# Connect to AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD

# Get the Azure AD Group
$azureAdGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $azureAdGroupName

if (-not $azureAdGroup) {
    Write-Host "Azure AD Group '$azureAdGroupName' not found."
    exit
}

# Get the resource group ID
$resourceGroupId = $resourceGroup.ResourceId

# Get the role definition for the Contributor role
$roleDefinition = Get-AzRoleDefinition -Name "Owner"

# Assign the role to the Azure AD group
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $azureAdGroup.ObjectId -RoleDefinitionName $roleDefinition.Name -Scope $resourceGroupId


# Get the PIM role settings for the resource group
$roleSettings = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleSetting -ProviderId "aadRoles" -ResourceId $resourceGroupId

if (-not $roleSettings) {
    Write-Host "No PIM role settings found for resource group '$resourceGroupName'."
    exit
}

# Enable PIM for the Azure AD group on the resource group
$roleSetting = $roleSettings | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Contributor" }

if (-not $roleSetting) {
    Write-Host "PIM role setting for 'Contributor' role not found."
    exit
}

# Update the role setting to enable PIM
Set-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleSetting -Id $roleSetting.Id -RoleMemberSettings @{ PermanentAssignment = $false; EligibleAssignment = $true; ApproverIdList = @($azureAdGroup.ObjectId) }

Write-Host "PIM configured for resource group '$resourceGroupName' and Azure AD group '$azureAdGroupName'."


Your script mixes AzureAD and Az modules, causing conflicts. Use the Az module for both Azure resources and Azure AD roles, and ensure PIM is configured for Azure AD roles, not just resource roles.

Any update on the issue?

To assign the owner role to the Azure AD group at resource group scope, make use of below PowerShell script:
# Login to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

# Variables
$subscriptionId = "SubID"
$resourceGroupName = "Ruk"
$azureAdGroupName = "DemoGroup03"
$roleName = "Owner" 

Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

# Get the Resource Group
$resourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName

if (-not $resourceGroup) {
    Write-Host "Resource group '$resourceGroupName' not found."
    exit
}

# Install and import the AzureAD module (if not installed)
if (-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name AzureAD)) {
    Install-Module -Name AzureAD -Force -AllowClobber
}

# Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD

# Get the Azure AD Group
$azureAdGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $azureAdGroupName

if (-not $azureAdGroup) {
    Write-Host "Azure AD Group '$azureAdGroupName' not found."
    exit
}

# Get the Resource Group ID
$resourceGroupId = $resourceGroup.ResourceId

# Get the Role Definition for the "Owner" role
$roleDefinition = Get-AzRoleDefinition -Name $roleName

# Assign the role to the Azure AD group at the resource group scope
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $azureAdGroup.ObjectId -RoleDefinitionName $roleDefinition.Name -Scope $resourceGroupId


The owner role is assigned to Azure AD group at resource group scope:


Note that: PIM roles are different than the IAM roles or Azure RBAC roles. Refer this blog for PIM roles.

Reference:
Assign eligibility for a group in Privileged Identity Management - Microsoft Entra ID Governance | Microsoft 

Thanks for the script, when I ran it the code creates a permanent role assignment, what I was looking to do is role assignment using privilege identity management such that the group will be eligible for the role rather than the role being permanently assigned to the AD group.
